# javascript send multiple file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, file-upload

In my form I have this script, but when I try to send the files (image), I have just only one one

```
var_dump($_POST['FILES'])`
```

I make a mistake maybe ?

```
$('select[name=\'type\']').on('change', function() {
    if (this.value == 'select' || this.value == 'radio' || this.value == 'checkbox' || this.value == 'image') {
    $('#option-value').parent().show();
    } else {
    $('#option-value').parent().hide();
    }
    });

    $('select[name=\'type\']').trigger('change');


    var option_value_row = <?php echo $i; ?>

    function addOptionValue() {
    html  = '<tr id="option-value-row' + option_value_row + '">';
    html += '  <td><input type="hidden" name="option_value[' + option_value_row + '][option_value_id]" value="" />';

    <?php
    for ($l=0, $n=count($languages); $l<$n; $l++) {
    ?>
    html += '<?php echo $OSCOM_Language->getImage($languages[$l]['code']); ?><input type="text" name="option_value[' + option_value_row + '][option_value_description][name][<?php echo  $l; ?>]" value="" class="form-control" required aria-required="true" />';
    html += '<input type="hidden" name="option_value[' + option_value_row + '][option_value_description][language_id][<?php echo $l; ?>]" value="<?php echo $OSCOM_Language->getID($languages[$l]['code']); ?>" class="form-control" />';
    <?php
       }
    ?>
    html += '  </td>';




    html += '  <td>';
    html += '    <input type="file" name="option_value[' + option_value_row + '][image]" value="" accept="image/*" class="form-control" />';
    html += '    <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="1024">';
    html += '  </td>';




    html += '  <td class="text-md-right"><input type="text" name="option_value[' + option_value_row + '][sort_order]" value="" class="form-control" /></td>';
    html += '  <td class="text-md-right"><button type="button" onclick="$(\'#option-value-row' + option_value_row + '\').remove();" data-toggle="tooltip" title="button_remove" class="btn btn-danger"><i class="fas fa-minus-circle"></i></button></td>';
    html += '</tr>';

    $('#option-value tbody').append(html);

    option_value_row++;
    }
```

Comment: Difficult to say as code look a little messy but your name attribute for file inputs look rather odd...

Comment: @Pierre : the pb come from ther : option_value[' + option_value_row + '][image] and when I make a var_dump($_FILES) on 2 files,  I have just one and not 2 ou 3 files.